# How to generate a print data file for Honeywell mobile computer to print on a Zebra Bluetooth printer by its utility, BTPrint.exe?

Tags: printing, bluetooth, windows-mobile, zebra-printers, honeywell

I have a Honeywell Dolphin 6510 mobile computer( hand-held device with Windows Mobile  6.0 OS ).

I want to develop an application which will be run on this mobile computer. The application needs to call a Honeywell device stock command utility, BTPrint.exe, to print on a Zebra Bluetooth printer. The path and filename of a print data file will be the value of 'CommandArgs' of the command, BTPrint.

This print data file needs to include the formatting commands for the printer used.

Here is the way about Honeywell devices printing on Bluetooth printers.
https://honeywellaidc.force.com/supportppr/s/article/How-to-print-a-label-on-a-Bluetooth-printer

Is there any sample code that reads a label format file created by Zebra Designer and then generates a print data file for Zebra printer which will be used by the  Honeywell print utility, BTPrint.exe?

Btw, I have tried to download and install Honeywell SDK several times in order to find some of these samples. But every time I failed in installing process. I wrote to its support email address for help, but have not gotten any reply. :-(

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: First, you need to contact the Honeywell support via their support portal, I assume the support email address (if any) is not watched. Second, are you shure BTprint.exe supports a cmd arg for the print file? Third, what about the BT printer address? You need to select the printer in BTprint manually.

Comment: - The honeywell article does not say that you can call BTprint.exe with a cmd arg. BTprint uses a file with descriptions and associated data files to present these in BTprint exe for selection.

Comment: Thanks josef for your reply.
1. I will try to contact Honeywell via another method.
2. There are several print demos in Honeywell device. And they also call BTPrint.exe with a print data file.
3. The print demos have not any options for printer selection yet. I will go on studying.

Comment: You are right, BTprint.exe is called with an arg for the print file. The Printer Demo uses a data file with descriptions and file names and then launches BTprint.exe with the file name for the selected demo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last, I found that we can generate these print data files( .prn for Toshiba TEC portable printer ) with utility, BarTender, which is a 3rd-party tool some like Zebra Designer.

And, I actually printed out on a TEC printer with the command "BTPrint.exe \Temp\mytec.prn" running on my Honeywell mobile computer.

In fact, we also can generate a print data file for Zebra printer with utility, Zebra Designer.

For you all reference.

Answer (score 1):

This is my finding so far:

## How the Print Demo works

The Printing Demo application is controlled by exm files. To extend the list of available print samples, merge the new files and information into the exm file. The print files hold everything needed to print a demo label or receipt in the printing language understood by the printer.

1. copy the device file "\Honeywell\PrintDemoMenu.exm" to the PC.
2. Open PrintDemoMenu.exm with a Text-only editor, for example Windows Notepad, on the PC.
3. Insert new lines in the following form for every new print file (here csim2receipt.prn):

   ```
   <Section desc="" flags="128" name="PrintCSIM2receiptBT">
       <Key flags="16" name="Name">Intermec (BT,CSIM,2inch) Receipt Print</Key>
       <Key flags="16" name="Description">Print 2inch Receipt to an Intermec printer in CSIM</Key>
       <Key flags="16" name="CommandLine">$(InstallDir)\Power Tools\btprint.exe</Key>
       <Key flags="16" name="CommandArgs">"$(InstallDir)\Demos\csim2receipt.prn"</Key>
   ```
4. Copy the menu exm back to the device.
5. Start Printer demo on device and check for the new entry.

UPDATE: see [BTPrint.exe Sample with Zebra Designer](http://www.hjgode.de/temp/BTPrint.pdf)

Comment: Thank you josef. In fact, I have studied PrintDemoMenu.exm. But where is csim2receipt.prn and where is it from? Are you sure that it is specific to the Toshiba TEC printer?

Comment: The file csim2receipt.prn was used as an example for a new print demo file only. You can create your own print file and add it to the print demo application. But as you asked first, you can just use BTprint.exe directly with a file of your choice. Why start you writing about "Tochiba TEC printer"?